# Firebase hosting - Load scripts from unauthenticated sources

Tags: javascript, firebase, https, firebase-hosting

first, I deployed a website using Firebase hosting.
then, bought a domain from Godaddy, and linked them together.

note: everthing working great so far - https etc.

But, when loading the site(with chrome) I get this error:

> This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources

Example in https://saharmillis.info/

[image]

[image]

[image]

When pressing the "load unsafe scripts" the HTTP get cancelled.

In the console I get some errors about link by http instead of https,
but all my CSS files & scripts, located on my Firebase host locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the developer console of Chrome, you will see very explicit errors with the URLs that cause the problem:

> http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxolIZu-HDpmDIZMigmsroc4.woff2
>
> http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidsans/v6/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2

So your code is (directly or indirectly) loading fonts that are served over HTTP. Note that `fonts.gstatic.com` can serve the files over HTTPS as well. So if you find where the includes come from, you can just replace `http://` with `https://` to get rid of the error.

Update: a quick check shows that the URLs are in the files in your font folder. E.g. `Droid+Sans.css`:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Droid Sans'), local('DroidSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidsans/v6/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Comment: tnx dude.. U ROCK..  forgot about urls in CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced all the
"http://"
to 
"//"

Just in case...